# I try to do a threading system in Python but I can't

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm trying to make a threading system that continuously runs a while cycle but at the same time performs another function that is waiting for a string.

For example, a while cycle to write "Hello World" and a function waiting for something to be typed.

So i try with this code but it's not worked :(

```
import threading
from time import sleep
import time

data = []

def get_input():
    data.append(input()) # Something akin to this
    return data



input_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_input)
input_thread.start()


while (True):
        print ("Hello World")
        time.sleep(1)

input_thread.join()

if data.pop=="a":
    print ("This message will be writed, only when user typed something")
```

Comment: You've got an infinite loop. Why did you expect your code to go past the infinite loop?

Comment: try `data.pop()` - `data.pop` is a builtin function - you have to call it as a function to get a result that might be comparable to `'a'`. But yes you should probably ditch the infiinite loop as that will never get to the join. Maybe you could test the length of `data`? Also, the Python way is `while True:` - no need for the brackets around `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

- Check the array length before popping
- The input thread must have a loop also
- You need to press enter when you input a string

Here is the updated code:

```
import threading
from time import sleep
import time

data = []

def get_input():
    while True:
        data.append(input()) # must press enter to submit

input_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_input)
input_thread.start()

while (True):
    print ("Hello World")
    time.sleep(1)
    if (len(data) and data.pop()=="a"):
        print ("This message will be writed, only when user typed something")
            
input_thread.join()  # never gets here
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted so the post is removed from the "No Answer" list. Thanks.